# How to display the uploaded preview image differently for every instance in one page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, file-upload, upload, filereader

Hello Frontend Developers,

Currently working on a Wordpress plugin and I want an upload field to attach featured image from frontend. I am using javascript FileReader to link the preview image. Plugin main page is displaying a set of posts from Custom Post Type which the user can edit multiple items together with one save action.

Problem: When I change one image for specific post it changes all the preview images of opened edit screens.

Function is calling on file change event

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        jQuery(".testio_upload_wrap").css(
          "background",
          "url(" + e.target.result + ")"
        );

        jQuery(".testio_upload_label").text("");
        jQuery(".clear_image_path").show();
      };
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<div class="testio_form_wrapper">
  <form id="testioform" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div id="testio-text">
        <div id="testio-response">
           <div class="message"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="testioTitle" name="testioTitle" placeholder="Put Name"/><br />

        <textarea id="testioContents" name="testioContents"  rows="10" cols="20" placeholder="Put Testimonial Content"></textarea>

        <div class="testio_upload_wrap">
           <label class="testio_upload_label" for="main_image">Upload Photo</label>
           
           <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" class="testio_upload" name="main_image" id="main_image"  multiple="false" value="" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif"/>
           
           <a class="clear_image_path">X</a> 
           <div class="progressBar" >
              <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"><span id="percent"></span></div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <a class="testio_btn crateTestioBtn" onclick="testioAddPost(testioTitle.value,testioContents.value);" style="cursor: pointer">Create Post</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Is there a way I could call same function for every upload element but only set the preview for its parent only not all the other items.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)  to target the specific instance starting from the known element `input`

```
jQuery(input).closest(".testio_upload_wrap").css(
      "background",
      "url(" + e.target.result + ")"
    );
```

Comment: I tried both but every element is setting the preview in first box only. Like when I change the second box image, it changes the first one's image.

Comment: here is a quick demo I made. after using parents() now the first image only get changes.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddXpbE